# Postgres decimal precision VS Excel

Tags: excel, postgresql, types, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am looking for any documentation on the decimal precision in Postgres and Excel.

I have a database which was imported through excel. I am finding that the `SUM()` result in excel is slightly different than the `SUM()` method in Postgres (usually at the 3rd or 4th decimal place depending on what i include or exclude from the data. I am curious to see if this is because of a floating point precision issue, or if there may be some small differences resulting from the import.

Comment: `1`. What do you expect to achieve here? `2`. These are fairly two, very different technology platforms e.g. Excel is meant for rather/relatively _simple_ calculations where as the other is a database a perfect container to hold any type at its best (given how perfect the container's DNA)

Comment: Simple enough to find for Excel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: I need to have an answer as to why they are different. The client is expecting a 100% match, which is not the case. The xlxs file was used to create the database, so I expect them to be the same as well

Comment: If you need an answer as to why some specific case shows a difference, then you need to provide details on the case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the data, queries, and the differing results, rather than just broadly describing them. Also, what *exactly* is the data type of the column in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find documentation for Postgres [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

PostgreSQL's [`decimal`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) is *not* a floating point number, but an arbitrary precision number. Additions like `sum()` are *exact* in Postgres.

> The types decimal and numeric are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

In contrast, MS Excel operates with limited accuracy. [Quoting Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) at the site [@Tim provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493490/postgres-decimal-precision-vs-excel#comment34221436_22493490):

> As with other spreadsheets, Microsoft Excel works only to limited
>   accuracy because it retains only a certain number of figures to
>   describe numbers (it has limited precision)

Discrepancies are to be expected. You might try PostgreSQL's [double precision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) type, which seems a better match. I doubt, you'll get a 100% match, though.